# Javascript to figure out which button was pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a bit of Javascript determine which button was pressed in a form. This is my code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save">
<button onclick="window.location = 'admin.php'" name="new" type="button">New</button>
<button id="deletebutton" value="30" name="del" type="submit">Delete</button>
```

These are all submitted to a Javascript function called formValidation, like so:

```
<form name="addorg" action="addorg.php" onSubmit="return formValidation()" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

I want to write Javascript that figures out how to tell the difference between which button was pressed.

Comment: Please don't say thanks at the end of your posts. Thanks :)

Comment: I made a script that noted when the delete button was on there and through out an alert asking if you wanted to delete, but it was overly broad, and also worked for the save.

Comment: why are you using three diff type of button tags?? you can use any one for all threee.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to make these buttons *not* be submit buttons, give them all click handler, and put a simple data attribute on them (which could be read in the click handler):

```
<input onclick="subForm()" data-type="save" type="button" value="Save">
<button onclick="subForm()" data-type="del" id="deletebutton" value="30" name="del"  type="button" >Delete</button>

function subForm(){
   var buttonType = this.getAttribute("data-type");
   //do somethig with buttonType
   document.forms["addorg"].submit();

}
```

Comment: Now it won't delete, the information isn't being sent via POST.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
 })
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mikulgohil/ecDPa/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of onsubmit attribute in the form, you can use onclick event on the button to invoke the form validation function, and pass to it the clicked button details. Add the following attribute to each of the submit buttons:

```
onclick="formValidation(this.value)"
```

In JS:

```
function formValidation(value)
{
    //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function buttonclick(action)
{
document.addorg.action.value = action;
document.addorg.submit();
}
</script>


<form name="addorg" action="addorg.php" onSubmit="return formValidation()" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="action">
<input onclick=buttonclick('savebutton')  type="submit" value="Save">
<button onclick=buttonclick('newbutton') name="new" type="button">New</button>
<button onclick=buttonclick('delbutton') id="deletebutton" name="del" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```